# StartSSL Class 1 Client cert missing private key in Keychain Access?

Tags: certificate, private-key, client-certificate

I have been using Class 1 Client Certificates from StartSSL for a while now (in OS X to sign my emails via S/MIME). I went to renew yesterday and I received my new cert.  However, I am unsure how to get my private key (self-generated on my computer) in the proper format for installation.  I did get the cert installed in `Keychain Access.app`, but there is no private key associated with it.  (I generated my own private key/`.csr` file with `openssl` as I have done in the past.)

What am I missing here? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Love too get driveby downvotes

Comment: @Spiff I updated the question with better wording as to the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to form the file necessary to import to Keychain Access, from the downloaded cert and my private key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <my .crt from StartSSL> -inkey <private key I generated with openssl> -out mycert.pfx
```

Then double-clicking mycert.pfx installs it in `Keychain Access.app` and `Mail.app` can automatically use it at that point.

Comment: @Spiff I updated the wording to reflect what actually happened.